# Trying to add an event to google places

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use the Google Place Actions API, specifically the events and I cannot get a valid post for the life of me.

Here is the URL I am using:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?sensor=false&key=placesApiKey&duration=26000&reference=CjQwAAAAv4TTQ3ySXiGhOElWFNAQ-roLOfgwo215yRTk1Bmhg0jSJ-sAdz9nHgNgnGBAmqP7EhC7K0AjTfFcZgCUh68c2yNtGhRkmynXvE5d4XA5ZfyBqAxlNdsAIg&summary=this is going to be something fun

The reference is to Tempe, AZ. I keep getting a 404 back saying that it is an illegal request. Any help would be great! I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have tried three different ways both with the same results:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler());

String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?sensor=false&key=" + googlePlacesAPIKey;
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
NameValuePair[] data = {
        new NameValuePair("duration", Long.toString(duration)),
        new NameValuePair("reference", reference),
        new NameValuePair("summary", summary)
    };

post.setRequestBody(data);
```

and

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?sensor=false&key=" + googlePlacesAPIKey);

try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("duration", Long.toString(duration)));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reference", reference));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("summary", summary));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
}
```

and

```
URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?sensor=false&key="+googlePlacesAPIKey+"&duration="+duration+"&reference="+reference+"&summary="+summary);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter( httpCon.getOutputStream());
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage()); out.close();
```

and

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?sensor=false&key=" + googlePlacesAPIKey);
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

object.put("duration", Long.toString(duration));
object.put("reference", reference);
object.put("summary", summary);

String message = object.toString();

post.setEntity(new StringEntity(message));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Here is the link to the API for those that are curious:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#event_add

Comment: How are you sending the HTTP POST request?

Comment: Hello! I just added to my question the code I am using. I was using the apache HTTPClient before but then went to the simple stuff in already in the Java library.

Comment: Added another way that is still failing on me...

Comment: Hi Chris, would I get a different error other than invalid request if something was wrong with my key? I honestly have no idea what I am doing wrong. Sorry if this is a no brainer!

Comment: If your key was incorrect you would receive `"status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"`

Comment: Okay, yeah I have not gotten that status yet. I am still stuck at invalid request. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can do like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8

import sys
import urllib

parameters = urllib.urlencode({
    'key' : "YOUR_API_KEY",
    'sensor' : 'false'
  })
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?%s" % (parameters)

#The reference
reference = "CoQBdgAAAN4u...YKmgQ"

#Add event
postdata = '''
{
  "duration": 86400,
  "language": "ja",
  "reference": "%s",
  "summary": "Event Name!",
  "url" : "http://hogehoge.com/test_page"
}
''' % (reference)

f = urllib.urlopen(url, postdata)
print f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for the python solution! I am looking for a Java one though. Sorry, I should have mentioned it before :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not good for Java though, I created an example code for Android Java.

### [MainActivity.java]

```
package com.example.placeseventtest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private final String API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
  private PlacesHTTP myUtil;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView resTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
    myUtil = new PlacesHTTP(API_KEY, resTxtView);


    Button currentPosBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.currentPosBtn);
    currentPosBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray types = new JSONArray();
        try {
          location.put("lat", 123.4556);
          location.put("lng", 123.4556);

          params.put("location", location);
          params.put("accuracy", 20);
          params.put("name", "Event Name");

          //only one type is available.
          types.put("parking");
          params.put("types", types);

          params.put("language", "en");
        } catch (Exception e) {}


        // Show the request JSON data.
        TextView reqTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.requestText);
        try {
          reqTxtView.setText(params.toString(2));
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        // POST to Google Server
        myUtil.execute(params);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

---

### [PlacesHTTP.java]

```
package com.example.placeseventtest;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlacesHTTP extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, HttpResponse>{

  private HttpPost post;
  private HttpClient httpClient;
  private String url;
  private TextView txtView;

  public PlacesHTTP(String api_key, TextView resultView) {
    url = String.format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=false&key=%s", api_key);
    txtView = resultView;
  }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  }


  @Override
  protected HttpResponse doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
    //Send data as JSON format
    JSONObject opts = params[0];
    StringEntity strEntity;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
      strEntity = new StringEntity(opts.toString());
      post.setEntity(strEntity);
      response = httpClient.execute(post);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {
    if (result != null) {
      // Display the result
      try {
        txtView.setText(EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity()));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    } else {
        txtView.setText("null");
    }
  }
}
```

---

I got this result:

[image]

Comment: The above textarea shows the sent data, and the below textarea shows the result from Places API.

Comment: Have you tried the add event to a place? The URL is a bit different. Also, is the http apache client you are using only for droid? Mine looks a bit different. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think your code is wrong where you send the all parameters as POST method. You need to send your APIKEY and sensor parameters as GET parameter, and another ones are POST. I think that is the problem.

Comment: Do you mean put the sensor and key back in the URL and only have the other 3 parameters in the body? I update the code to show what I changed. Still failed on me.

Comment: I changed the http client to the same library you are using with still no luck. You can see it as the second example I tried.